# What is the type for ActionReducerMap?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint, ngrx

The following line

```
const reducers: ActionReducerMap<any> = {};
```

throws the error:

```
ESLint: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)
```

I'd like to know what the type for ActionReducerMap is?

Can I set it explicitly?

```
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production ? [logger] : [];

interface State {
  router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<BaseRouterStoreState>;
}

const reducers: ActionReducerMap<any> = {};

export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): ActionReducer<State> {
  return (state, action) => {
    const result = reducer(state, action);
    console.groupCollapsed(action.type);
    console.log('prev state', state);
    console.log('action', action);
    console.log('next state', result);
    console.groupEnd();
    return result;
  };
}
```

Here is my full code:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictActionImmutability: true,
        strictStateImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Try using `T` or `?` or `Object`

Comment: For, T I get the error `TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.`

Comment: For Object, I get the error `TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducerMap<Object, Action>'.   Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.     Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<Function, Action>'.       Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(state: Function | undefined, action: Action): Function'.`

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure why `any` isn't working in this case

Comment: Well in the end I would say that give it the type its being used for. Which means using `<State>` and if there's some other type that you need to use then put it along with it using the or operator `|`

Answer (score 1):

You should define an interface:

```
export interface AppState {
    storeBooks: ReadonlyArray<book>;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    storeBooks: undefined
};
```